# MongoDB Compass: select distinct field values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am using MongoDB Compass and don't have Mongo Shell. I need to build a query using MongoDB Compass tool to select distinct values of the "genre" field from my collection.

[image: compass tool screenshot]

Sample Input:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"58c59c6a99d4ee0af9e0c34e"},"title":"Bateau-mouche sur la Seine","year":{"$numberInt":"1896"},"imdbId":"tt0000042","genre":["Documentary”,”Short”],"viewerRating":{"$numberDouble":"3.8"},"viewerVotes":{"$numberInt":"17"},"director":"Georges Mlis"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"58c59c6a99d4ee0af9e0c340"},"title":"Watering the Flowers","year":{"$numberInt":"1896"},"imdbId":"tt0000035","genre":["Short”],"viewerRating":{"$numberDouble":"5.3"},"viewerVotes":{"$numberInt":"33"},"director":"Georges M�li�s"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"58c59c6a99d4ee0af9e0c34a"},"title":"The Boxing Kangaroo","year":{"$numberInt":"1896"},"imdbId":"tt0000048","genre":["Short”],"viewerRating":{"$numberDouble":"5.2"},"viewerVotes":{"$numberInt":"48"},"director":"Birt Acres"}
```

**Expected output**: Documentary, Short

Comment: _"... don't have mongo Shell"_,  A MongoDB installation includes Mongo Shell program. _Also_, please post text of a sample document (you can copy from Compass).

Comment: Thanks Prasad for your response. I installed only MongoDB Compass and connecting to MongoDB Atlas cluster. I know how to create the query in mongo shell to select distinct fields. just curious to learn, how to achieve the same with compass tool as I will be using it frequently. will attach few test docs.

Comment: You can use [Compass's Aggregation Pipeline Builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/)  to create aggregattion queries using grouping to get count, sum, average, etc. Also, see [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) and [Aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can do this via aggregation framework in Compass, using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). The $unwind is performed to create a unique document for each element in the target array, which enables the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator in the $group stage to then capture the genres as distinct elements.

Pipeline:

```js
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$genre',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      uniqueGenres: { $addToSet: '$genre' }
    }
  }
]
```

See screenshot below for Compass example:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. just a quick question how to convert "Short,Documentary" to array, pl suggest

Comment: In the output above, "Short", "Documentary" are an array within the field `distinctGenres` in the single document that is returned.

If you want to the final output to just be an array, then you can do that in your server-side code.

i.e.

```javascript
const pipeline = [
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$genre',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      uniqueGenres: { $addToSet: '$genre' }
    }
  }
];
const [{ distinctGenres }] = await db.getCollection('docs').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have created my pipeline based on your inputs, kindly review and suggest if I missed anything.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not your own slight modification.

Comment: I didn't need the path but the group provided exactly what I needed for my use case.  Thank you for your post.

Comment: how can i download the filtered records